# Submit form with AJAX inside table loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table and inside this table I run a while loop with a form.
I submit this form with Ajax.

For example:

The while loop gave 5 results, so I have 5 buttons with different hidden data.
When I press the first button, I get the right data back from Ajax, but when I press the other buttons, I get no result back from Ajax.

I use a table because of the search function, so I want to keep it as a table.

```js
(function($) {
  function jobDetails(e) {
    var formData = $('#jobForm').serialize() //serialize data from form
    $.ajax({
      url: 'jobdetails.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      data: formData,
      success: function(data, textStatus) {
        // success
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  $('#jobForm').click(jobDetails);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Wat zoekt u?" onkeydown="onkeypressed(event, this);">
  </div>

  <span class="counter pull-right"></span>

  <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-bordered results" id="searchTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="warning no-result">
        <td colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
            if(isset($_GET['search'])){
            $resource_id = ($_GET['machine']);
                $jobs = "SELECT * FROM ";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($jobs);
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form id="jobForm" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="machine" value="<?php echo $resource_id; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="base" value="<?php echo $row[" WORKORDER_BASE_ID "]; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="<?php echo $row[" WORKORDER_LOT_ID "]; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="split" value="<?php echo $row[" WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID "]; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="<?php echo $row[" WORKORDER_SUB_ID "]; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="seq" value="<?php echo $row[" SEQUENCE_NO "]; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="part" value="<?php echo $row[" PART_ID "]; ?>">
              <button id="jobdetails" type="button" class="btn btn-default col-lg-12">                
                                    <?php echo $row["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"]."/".$row["WORKORDER_LOT_ID"].".".$row["WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID"]."-".$row["WORKORDER_SUB_ID"].":".$row["SEQUENCE_NO"];?>         
                                </button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the problem with your code is you cannot have multiple Id with same name.
That's the basic rule. So to avoid that class name functionality exists.

This is your html I have made id unique of all the forms, so we can easily pick which needs to be submitted, I have also added Class to button and custom data attribute through which we can get current_id of the form. I am hoping that id is the unique record in all the rows.

```
<?php
            if(isset($_GET['search'])){
            $resource_id = ($_GET['machine']);
                $jobs = "SELECT * FROM ";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($jobs);
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    ?> 
                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                            <form id="jobForm_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">                           
                                <input type="hidden" name="machine" value="<?php echo $resource_id; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="base" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_LOT_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="split" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_SUB_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="seq" value="<?php echo $row["SEQUENCE_NO"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="part" value="<?php echo $row["PART_ID"]; ?>">
                                <button id="jobdetails" class="buttonsubmit" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default col-lg-12">                
                                    <?php echo $row["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"]."/".$row["WORKORDER_LOT_ID"].".".$row["WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID"]."-".$row["WORKORDER_SUB_ID"].":".$row["SEQUENCE_NO"];?>         
                                </button> 
                            </form>                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

You dont need parent and other fields, you can simply pass the current id of the form and take that particular form:

Now on Button click:

```
    $('.buttonsubmit').click( function(){    
        var unique_form_id = $(this).data('id');
        jobDetails(unique_form_id);
    });

    function jobDetails(unique_id){
        var formData = $("#jobForm_".unique_id).serialize() //// Changed from direct #id to this object so it always refers to the clicked button.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jobdetails.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            success: function( data, textStatus ){
                // success
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: I dont have an unique id in my row. I changed it too $i and increase it by $i++, but my POST parameter is empty

Comment: Post paramter means?

Comment: $_POST is empty. It should have all the hidden inputs inside it

Comment: `var formData = $("#jobForm_".unique_id).serialize()` this wil give 'undentified' so I changed it with `unique = var+var` and `var formData = $(unique).serialize()`

Answer (score 2):

You are using while loop to generate forms but you are using `id` attribute for the form tag that is wrong. As you said, if there are 5 forms, there will be 5 same `id="jobForm"` but `id` should be unique in a page. Use class instead. 
Check the changes I made in the following piece of code:

```
<?php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    ?> 
                    <tr>
                        <td> 
                            <form id="jobForm" class="jobForm" method="post"> // added class attribute with form tag.                           
                                <input type="hidden" name="machine" value="<?php echo $resource_id; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="base" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="lot" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_LOT_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="split" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="sub" value="<?php echo $row["WORKORDER_SUB_ID"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="seq" value="<?php echo $row["SEQUENCE_NO"]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="part" value="<?php echo $row["PART_ID"]; ?>">
                                <button id="jobdetails" class="jobdetails" type="button" class="btn btn-default col-lg-12">                
                                    <?php echo $row["WORKORDER_BASE_ID"]."/".$row["WORKORDER_LOT_ID"].".".$row["WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID"]."-".$row["WORKORDER_SUB_ID"].":".$row["SEQUENCE_NO"];?>         
                                </button> 
                            </form>                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                <?php
                }



(function($){
        function jobDetails( this,e ){
            var formData = this.parents('form:first').serialize() //// Changed from direct #id to this object so it always refers to the clicked button.
            $.ajax({
                url: 'jobdetails.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                success: function( data, textStatus ){
                    // success
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('.jobForm').click( function(){    // Changed from id (#) to class (.)
            $this = $(this);
            jobDetails($this, event);
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: An error on "this" in function jobDetails( this,e ){.

Comment: Oh, yes, there was a minor mistake. Try the function now.

Comment: I had to change `function jobDetails( $this,e ){ ` and `var formData = $this.parents('form:first').serialize()` too with '$this' instead of 'this'. I get response from ajax but the POST is empty...

Comment: You are saying that POST is empty, means the request parameter using POST is empty??

Comment: Yes. The parameter POST is empty

Comment: Can you post a screenshot here? I can not understand what will be the problem! Because we did not make any changes which would not pass form parameters.

Comment: In the file jobdetails.php I only have `var_dump($_POST)`. So in my network console I should see the input data from the form, but the var_dump array is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198161/discussion-between-himanshu-upadhyay-and-rico-krouweel).